# search-google-geocode : taking a long time to install

Tags: node.js, google-maps, ubuntu

've search the internet but I could not find antyhing relevant.

I'm trying to install that package. One hour or later and it is still installing.

I've done a `ps aux | grep npm` and nothing relevant.

I've done a `top`and still nothing relevant.

I'm using a virtualbox with the lastest ubuntu in it.

Link is below

https://www.npmjs.org/package/search-google-geocode

Have you encounter something similar? (not sure if I'm on the right forum but if no, I'll delete my post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just installed it from my laptop and it took about 1 second to install -- you might have experienced some npm delays, or possibly an ISP issue.

Comment: Hi Randall, 

Indeed. I've tried to install it on a corporate network. I had a test on a outside network and it worked as a charm -_- 

Thanks.